# SharePoint 2010: How to call two or more consecutive workflows for one item in Timer Job?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I'm trying to create a Timer Job to call 2 workflows once in a day for a list items.
To make it a bit more clear: 1st workflow(workflowName) changes the field value from Yes to No and sents an E-mail, the 2nd one(workflowName1) changes some values in the one of two others lists, depending on the first list values.
So, here is my method for starrting workflow:

```
     private void startWorkflow(string wfName, SPSite site, SPList list, SPListItem item)
    {
            SPWorkflowManager manager = site.WorkflowManager;
            SPWorkflowAssociation association = list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(wfName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            string data = association.AssociationData;
            SPWorkflow wf = manager.StartWorkflow(item, association, data, true);
     }
```

And here is my method call:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            startWorkflow(workflowName, site, list, item);
            startWorkflow(workflowName1, site, list, item);
        }
```

After starting the Timer Job, I see that 1st workflow call runs successfully, while calling the 2nd one returns an error :

> FAILED hr detected (hr = 0x8102008a)

After some research I figured out that problem occurs because some Item metadata is changed after the 1st wf execution (one field changes its value from Yes to No, as I said above).

How can I override it and call 2 wf at one item?
Thanks,
Anton.